# what type of errors can we handle using system define unnamed exception in sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I have been trying to access the below code

```
DECLARE
       N_DEPTNO DEPT.DEPTNO %TYPE :=&DEPT_NUM;
       V_DNAME DEPT.DNAME %TYPE;
       NOT_ENOUGH_VALUES EXCEPTION;
       PRAGMA
             EXCEPTION_INIT(NOT_ENOUGH_VALUES,-06502);
BEGIN
       SELECT DNAME,LOC INTO DNAME FROM DEPT
       WHERE DEPTNO = N_DEPTNO;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Successfully Fetched !!');
EXCEPTION
       WHEN NOT_ENOUGH_VALUES THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Enough Values ... ');
END;
```

It is still showing error message after specified it in EXCEPTION block.

Can i handle these type of errors using `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT`
i.e not providing enough values in the select statement...

If not what type of errors can be handled in `System Defined Unnamed Exception` 
using `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception handlers can catch runtime errors.  They cannot catch compilation errors.  The compiler figures out when it is compiling your code that it is syntactically invalid-- not enough values are specified in the `INTO` clause.  So the exception is raised before your code is executed.